# Getting started with triggers

Tags: trigger

I am new to Apex programming and am trying to play around with different uses for triggers. Currently, I am trying to create a trigger that when a custom *text* field on our *Opportunity* object is changed from NULL to any other value it will update a *checkbox* PO_Received from FALSE to TRUE on a custom object RFQ__c.

Could anyone help with providing some example pseudocode or similar that will assist in completing this task?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to first try your hands on Trailhead. We have one trailhead module available for trigger.

[Get Started with Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_triggers/units/apex_triggers_intro)

Once you complete this trailhead your current requirement will be very easy for you. In case if you still face any issue then share what did you try so far so community can assist you in better way.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that Trailhead, You can explore following regarding trigger:-

1. [Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm)
2. [Trigger Syntax](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_syntax.htm)
3. [Trigger Context Variables](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)
4. [Defining Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_defining.htm)
5. [Triggers and Order of Execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)
6. [Trigger and Bulk Request Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

These will provide more insight on triggers and their best practices and consideration.

And, Please provide the relationship between your Opportunity and RFQ__c so that I can provide you a sample code.